# C++ loop hangs if any code is added inside if Condition

Tags: c++, for-loop

I have the following code with strange behaviour:

```
struct Mime {
    int key;
    string value;
};

class Storage {

private:

    int Size;
    Mime * _storage;
    int last = 0;

public:

    Storage(int __size) {
        Size = __size;
        _storage = new Mime[Size + 2];
    }

    void add(const Mime & __mime) {

        for (int x = 0; x < last; x++)
            if (_storage[x].key == __mime.key) {}

        _storage[last++] = __mime;
    }
};

void test2() {

    int thisSize = 1000000;
    Storage storage(thisSize);
    auto start_t = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < thisSize; i++) {
        Mime temp;
        temp.key = i;
        temp.value = "Hey";
        storage.add(temp);
    }
    cout << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start_t).count() << " milliseconds\n" << endl;
}


int main() {

    test2();

    cout << "Done" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This code run in 120 milliseconds for me. But when I add some code here inside the `{}`

```
if (_storage[x].key == __mime.key) {}
```

like

```
if (_storage[x].key == __mime.key) { return; }
```

or anything else...
Then my program runs in 10 mins or sometimes hangs by adding `return;` or any other code. When I add  `return;` or any other code in this `if` condition, my program hangs. In this (if) nothing happens in the process because this doesn't seem to run the `return;` or any other code.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do not prefix variable names with underscores. Double underscores are reserved for internal stuff

Comment: The line `_storage[last++] = __mime;` is suspicious.

Comment: the code is true ... please run it in your system ... there is no problem with this _storage[last++] = __mime;

Comment: Please get some coding standards re: capitalisation amongst others See http://www.esa.int/TEC/Software_engineering_and_standardisation/TECRFBUXBQE_0.html

Comment: `if (_storage[x].key == __mime.key) {}` - What is the point of this line of code?

Comment: to check for unique key exists and if exists, just modify the value and not add new one ... some thing like std::map ...

Comment: Hence what is the point of the `for` loop

Comment: It does not - It does a comparison and then does nothing with the result

Comment: If you don't have any code inside the if-statement, the optimizer might remove it *and* the for-loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing strange with this behavior. It's the optimizer that recognizes that the `for` loop could safely not be executed at all if it has an empty block inside.

The optimizer says:

```
for (int x = 0; x < last; x++)
    if (_storage[x].key == __mime.key) {}
```

look this for has no side effects...which mean, that this bunch of lines does even if executed do not change the state of the program, so, I'd better save some time and not execute it.

Try to compile with -O0 you will still get a `long` runtime.

---

In order to double check that this is the cause, one can trick the compiler and force to keep that code using `volatile`

So the following code won't be optimized away and not matter what is the content of the `for`

```
  for (volatile int x = 0; x < last; x++){
      //whatever
   }
```

Comment: i just made something like map to check if there is that key inside the storage, do not create new one (unique key) and just change that value which here there is no any equal key and all are new so if (_storage[x].key == __mime.key) never true and there is no problem here ... but my problem is if i add something inside this condition like up, my program hang while this never TRUE

Comment: @MyJustWorking the problem is not the content of the `if`. What you're trying to do has quadratic cost cause for each add you check the whole array with that `for`. So when you add the first element the for runs for `0` iteration, then for `1` than for `2` which translates to `0+1+2+3..k-1` which is quadratic.  It's pretty normal that it takes a long time to execute. try to get rid of that `for` using an `unordered_set`

Comment: what exactly std::map do? map need to check the key too (to check if exists modify the value) not create new one !!!!

Comment: @MyJustWorking you can use a map where the key is the string and the value is the position into the array. whenever you want to add a new element you first check if it's already present, querying the `map`. if the answer is positive you then modify the element at position returned by the map. Otherwise, you add the element at the end of the array, making sure you update the map with the new information. That should be much faster. Something like an order of magnitude faster.